# Use an array as a class filter to check if elements have classes that were found in that array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, class

I know it sounds a bit confusing.
Here is what I'm trying to do:

I have five pictures,
each of the picture has a set of classes,
each time when clicked on one of the pictures the id (same as class name) will be pushed in to an array.

At the end, I want to only show the pictures if they contain the same classes (id) found in that array.

```
<div id="cameras" class="row text-center ">

    <div id="d5" class=" professional landscape wedding micro sportaction wildlife portrait astrophotographer cameras">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="images/d5.png" alt="D5">

        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="d810a" class=" professional landscape astrophotographer portrait micro cameras">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="images/d810a.png" alt="D3300">

        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="d810" class=" professional landscape wedding micro portrait cameras">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="images/d810.png" alt="D810">

        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="d750" class=" enthusiast landscape wedding micro sportaction wildlife portrait astrophotographer cameras">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="images/D750.png" alt="D750">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
$('#sportaction').on('click', function () {

 if ($("#sportaction").attr('data-click-state') == 1) {
     $(this).attr('data-click-state', 0);

     $("#snaButton").css({ fill: "#00725C" });

 } else {
     $(this).attr('data-click-state', 1);

     $("#snaButton").css({ fill: "#00A388" })

 }

});
$("#finish").click(function() {
 $("[data-click-state= '0' ]").each(function () {
    type_array.push($(this).attr("id"));

    //some.push(this.id);
    });
 });
```

For example: If I clicked on "enthusiast" and "landscape" Only d750 should show up.

The code below doesn't work.

```
$(".cameras").each(function () {
    $(this).hide();
    for (var i = 0; i < type_array.length; i++) {
        if ($(this).hasClass(type_array[i])) {
            $(this).show();

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: please show more code, the click handler at least. the pictures do not have any classes.

Comment: _"For example: If I clicked on "enthusiast" and "landscape" Only d750 should show up."_ All `.thumbnail` elements at `html` at Question appear to have `className` `"landscape"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know if I understand correctly your question, but try this?

```
var type_array = [];
$(".cameras").click(function() {
    var classArray = $(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/);
    $.each(classArray, function() {
        if (this.length > 0 && this != "cameras" && type_array.indexOf(this) == -1) {
            type_array[type_array.length] = this + "";
        }
    })
})
```

and somewhere else:

```
    $(".cameras").each(function () {

    $(this).hide();
    var clicked = this;
      var hasAllClasses = true;
    $.each(type_array,function(){
       if($(clicked).hasClass(this)){
          return true;
       }
         hasAllClasses=false;
         return false;
    });
     if(hasAllClasses===true){
    $(clicked).show();
     }

});
type_array=[];
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, but i need to be able to have more than one classes ,  for example if  i clicked on "enthusiast and sportaction" the d750 is the only one that has these two attributes

Comment: checking   Thank you su much

Comment: sorry, I dont know if it is working the way you need, but I have to leave now, I'll get back later, so if no-one else helps you, Ill try then

Comment: when it's done it show all the pictures, not the one with the classes we want. don;t know  if i'm doing something wrong

Comment: Please, check now, but all images will allways be visible, because they have common class "landscape", try to remove some classes and leave only a few to check if it works

Comment: I know, they have to have common classes cause they are in the same category, if i only choose landscape then all of them should show up, but if i choose both landscape and enthusiast then only the last picture should show, cause it is the only one with those two classes